# UNIX: passing value to IF condition instead of values

Tags: if-statement, awk

i am trying to write a code where i have used an IF statement.
here I am trying to compare 2 string that are obtained by using an awk statement.
Please help me...if this is possible.

```
if [ "awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt1.txt" -eq    "awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt2.txt" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, using `$()` or ``.

```
if [ $(awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt1.txt) -eq $(awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt2.txt) ]
```

If you want string comparison rather than numeric you probably want `=` instead of `-eq` though.

Might read better if you made a function too:

```
search_report() {
  awk "/$1/ { print \$3 }" $2
}

if [ $(search_report $search rpt1.txt) -eq $(search_report $search rpt2.txt) ]
...
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Daniel. I will proceed as your info.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture stdout into a variable like this:

```
variable=$(command)
```

Try this

```
rpt1=$(awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt1.txt)
rpt2=$(awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt2.txt)

if [ "${rpt1}" == "${rpt2}" ]; then
    echo "match";
fi
```

The operator `-eq` works with integers only, that's why I used `==` instead.

More about capturing stdout
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/

This is a excellent summary of operators in bash
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html